# Financial mathematics - earning compound interest

Tags: finance

This I assume is a very simple question but can't really wrap my head around it.

So the question is:

If 100 dollars is deposited at time t = 0 into an account earning 10%
interest and $20 is withdrawn at t = 1 and 2, then how much can be withdrawn at t = 3?

I tried getting the answer by doing this:
$$((100(1.1) - 20)(1.1)-20) = 79$$

But the solutions state:

$$100 (1.10)^
3 − 20 (1.10)^
2 − 20 (1.10) = 86.90$$

I have no idea of how this is correct.

p.s. This is my first post here. If there was something I did wrong, please let me know.

Comment: You forgot to factor in the interest gained at time 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go period by period.

$t=0$:  you put $\fbox {100}$ in the bank.

$t=1$ the $100$ has grown to $110$. You take out $20$, leaving you with $\fbox {90}$ in the bank.

$t=2$:  the $90$ has grown to $99$.  You take out $20$ leaving you with $\fbox {79}$ in the bank

$t=3$: The $79$ has grown to $79\times (1+.1)=\fbox {86.9}$

Comment: Thanks you. can't believe I made that silly mistake

Comment: No problem.  I always find that breaking it down period by period (by hand if it's easy, on a spreadsheet otherwise) clarifies things.  Closed formulas are nice, but they can be hard to apply consistently.